# Find maximum of three inputs

Tags: java, if-statement, logic, java.util.scanner

Here are the steps we need to take:

---

> a. Use the Scanner class to create an object to read input from the keyboard.
>
> b. Declare three int variables called x, y, z, and max.
>
> c. Prompt the user to enter a value for variables x, y, and z.
>
> d. Find the maximum of x, y, and z, then assign the maximum to max.
>
> e. Display the maximum.

My code seems to run endlessly whats wrong here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maximum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
        int max;

        System.out.print("Enter Value For x: ");
        x = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Value For y: ");
        y = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Value For z");
        z = keyboard.nextInt();

        max = Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z);

        if (x > y && x > z) {
            x = max;
        }
        if (y > x && y > z) {
            y = max;
        }
        if (z > x && z > y) {
            z = max; // Getting "assigned value is never used"
        }
        System.out.println("The Maximum is" + max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `max` back to `x`, `y` or `z`? Where was that specified, and where are you using it? How are you running this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran your code, there's no problem with it as far as I can see. It runs fine. It runs fine even if I remove your if statements (because the real maximum-determination is done by the code where `int max` is assigned.

I compressed the entire thing down to this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Value For x: ");
int x = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Value For y: ");
int y = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Value For z: ");
int z = scan.nextInt();

int max = Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z);
System.out.println("The Maximum is " + max);
```

And it outputs

```
Enter Value For x: 5
Enter Value For y: 10
Enter Value For z: 15
The Maximum is 15

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I modified your program a little bit. I declared the variables before creating a scanner object and it worked just fine. here's your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maximum {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int x;
int y;
int z;
int max;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Value For x: ");
x = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Value For y: ");
y = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Value For z: ");
z = keyboard.nextInt();

max = Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z);

if (x > y && x > z)
{
    x = max;
}
if (y > x && y > z)
{
    y = max;
}
if (z > x && z > y)
{
    z = max;  // Getting "assigned value is never used"
}
System.out.println("The Maximum is: " + max);
}
```

}

Sample output:

```
Enter Value For x: 6
Enter Value For y: 7
Enter Value For z: 5
The Maximum is: 7
```